# Is there a command to list AWS instances that results in short output?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have my AWS CLI set up and can use aws ec2 describe-instances to get the json object returned that describes all the known details of my instances. Is there an easy way to get just a short list, like instance name and instance id?

I want to be able to work with my instances on the command-line, but to get the instance ids (which commands like start-instances require), I have to scroll through all that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, via the `--query` option.

This option allows you to filter down and return specific elements from the structure.  There is a special wildcard `[*]` notation that allows you to iterate over lists of objects; we'll use this to iterate over the list of EC2 instances and return your desired values.

**Retrieving InstanceID, Instance Tag Name as JSON:**

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0]]'

[
    [
        [
            "i-abcd1234",
            "MyFirstInstance"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-efgh5678",
            "MySecondInstance"
        ]
    ]
]
```

**Retrieving InstanceID, Instance Tag Name as Text:**

If you don't want to work with json, you can also add the `--output` option to output text:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0]]' --output text

i-abcd1234      MyFirstInstance
i-efgh5678      MySecondInstance
```

Further reading:

- [AWS CLI Documentation - Controlling Command Output](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)